# SQL subset type filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a column with can be any of three possible elements, call them x,y,z. The column is not allowed to be only z.

I can imagine this in set theory where S = {x,y,z}, and I require all subsets of S except the set {z}.

How would I write a SQL statement that let's the column be any subset of x,y,z except z alone?

For example:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 1 | z |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | z |
| 3 | z |
| 3 | z |

Desired output:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 1 | z |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | z |

Comment: What do you mean here exactly? Are you asking how to create a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT` which is based on all values in a column, rather than the row that is being `INSERT`ed/`UPDATE`d?

Comment: See: [Create Check Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16) or on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

Comment: @Larnu yes a constraint on the table i.e. a where clause or case statement etc.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for how to write the check.
@BaronG can you please provide some example DDL/DML and an expected output.
Like:
`DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @Table (Col) VALUES
('x,y,z'),('x,z'),('z')`

Comment: I've added an example table with example outputs

Comment: This doesn't seem like a `CONSTRAINT`; this seems more like you need a correlated `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 3):

You may try with count window function as the following:

```
Select ID, Value
From
(
  Select ID, Value,
    Count(Case When Value = 'z' Then 1 End) Over (Partition By ID) As z_cnt, 
    Count(*) Over (Partition By ID) As all_cnt
  From table_name
) T
Where z_cnt <> all_cnt
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4QDcgY5T).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXCEPT` with your conditions

```
SELECT [ID], [Value] FROM tab
EXCEPT
SELECT [ID], [Value] FROm tab t1 WHERE  [Value] = 'z' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROm tab WHERE [ID] = t1.[ID]) = 1
```

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 1 | z |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | z |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0DnIh7W_)

If the data are not unique you can use `NOT IN` instead of

```
CREATE TABLE tab
    ([ID] int, [Value] varchar(1))
;
    
INSERT INTO tab
    ([ID], [Value])
VALUES
    (1, 'x'),
    (1, 'y'),
    (1, 'z'),
    (2, 'x'),
    (2, 'z'),
    (3, 'z'),
    (3, 'z'),
    (3, 'z'),
    (4, 'x'),
    (4, 'x'),
    (4, 'x'),
    (5, 'y'),
    (5, 'y'),
    (5, 'y')
;
```

```
14 rows affected
```

```
SELECT [ID], [Value] FROM tab
WHERE [ID] NOt IN (
SELECT [ID] FROm tab t1 WHERE  [Value] = 'z' 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT [Value]) FROm tab WHERE [ID] = t1.[ID]) = 1)
```

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | y |
| 1 | z |
| 2 | x |
| 2 | z |
| 4 | x |
| 4 | x |
| 4 | x |
| 5 | y |
| 5 | y |
| 5 | y |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SX92oiLC)

Comment: Thanks - there may be more than just one z row however

Comment: that needs only a small adjustment, and lease don't change the question so that it changes too much, only add new information to the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *exists* semi-join:

```
    select *
    from t
    where not exists (
        select *
        from t t2
        where t2.Id = t.Id and t.Value = 'Z'
        group by id 
        having Count(distinct value) = 1
    );
```